# Scale Down a Bitmap

Tags: android, image, bitmap, scale

I am trying to scale down a bitmap while keeping the same aspect ratio.
The following code works just ok, but I know its not the best approach.
I definitely do not like creating a holder bitmap and then another to scale it down as well.
Any suggestions on how to improve this are appreciated.

```
//width and height are passed in as params

    Bitmap viewBM = view.getBitMap();

    float aspectRatio = (float) width/height;        
    int newWidth= viewBM.getWidth();
    int newHeight = viewBM.getHeight();        

    if (newHeight > newWidth) {         
        newHeight= (int)Math.round(newWidth * aspectRatio);
    } else {
        newWidth= (int)Math.round(newHeight * aspectRatio);
    }        

    Bitmap holderBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap(viewBM, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);               
    final Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(holderBitmap, width, height, true);
```

Comment: I would recommend solution from this link: http://developer.sonymobile.com/2011/06/27/how-to-scale-images-for-your-android-application/

Comment: Thanks! Good article. Worked for me.